# Let's discuss on the parts of my friend's new PC build

Tags: gaming, processor, pc, hard-disk

**[Here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/registry/wishlist/2OK6I2T2BEWBD/ref=nav_wishlist_lists_2) is my list** of the parts on amazon of the new PC i am going to build for my friend. I need some experienced advice if that build is okay on that ~700 pounds budget or how it can be better on the same budget. This pc is mainly for gaming. Thanks.

I am considering to change the processor to ryzen 3 1300x and buy a small SSD to keep the budget but still be good for gaming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not asking for a hardware recommendation. Build reviews/requests are off-topic for this site, as they are quite broad.

Comment: If you would like an example of how to ask build request, please check out [these questions](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A60+is%3Aquestion+college). Disclosure: these are my questions.